# CSRF token with Apache Shiro

Tags: java, spring, csrf, shiro

I have an existing web application based on Apache Shiro for the authentication/authorization parts. I want to implement a mechanism for generating/checking an CSRF token, but there is no support for that in Shiro. I was thinking to use Spring Security for token generation and somehow pass the Shiro session to Spring. There is any clever way to do that ? or any other method to implement CSRF protection for a Shiro based app ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in Shiro out of the box.  A lot of frameworks that Shiro integrates with do provide this. (Tapestry, Spring, etc). So you may already that functionality available to you (depending on your stack)

That said, I do feel like this should be part of Shiro itself. I hacked on this feature a few months ago but I've been pretty busy lately...
I pushed that code here: https://github.com/bdemers/shiro/pull/1 if you want to take a look at it.